# symfony2 translation with transchoice

Tags: symfony, translation, yaml, twig, pluralize

I'm translating the following key in `activity.fr.yml`

```yaml
user.list.link: '{1}et %count% autre|]1,Inf[voir les %count% autres'
```

using tranchoice

```html
<a href="{{ moreLink }}" >{% transchoice count from "activity" %}user.list.link{% endtranschoice %}</a>
```

and I get the following error

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to choose a translation.")`

I think the translation has been found otherwise I wouldn't get an error about Unable to choose a translation but the key itself.

Also all the other keys from the same yaml even other tranchoice are well translated.

I followed the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/translation.html#twig-templates) and tried adding `with {'%count%': count}` with no success.

Does someone have an idea about what's wrong here ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax was fine but the value pass as %count% couldn't be negative neither equal to 0 because there was no {0} defintion in the pluralised string.
So I had a test to make sure the value was >= 0 and modified the string like this and it fixes it.

```yaml
user.list.link: '{0}|{1}et %count% autre|]1,Inf[voir les %count% autres'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need  to pass the parameter used to determine the translation which will be choose.

Look at the following example found [in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/translation.html#twig-templates):

```
{% transchoice count with {'%name%': 'Fabien'} from "app" %}
    {0} There is no apples|{1} There is one apple|]1,Inf] There are %count% apples
{% endtranschoice %}
```

Adapted to your example:

```
{% transchoice count with {'%count%': count} from "activity" %}
    user.list.link
{% endtranschoice %}
```

If it doesn't work, maybe your translation is not found. So, symfony use your key as fallback and cannot determine a valid choice because your key doesn't support this.

To check this, try to use a key like this:

```
user.list.link | user.list.link.many
```

Don't forget to use the same key in your activity catalog.

Comment: I think the translation has been found otherwise I wouldn't get an error about `Unable to choose a translation` but the key itself.

Comment: by adding your suggestion 
    `{% transchoice count with {'%count%':count} from "activity" %}user.list.link.link|user.list.many{% endtranschoice %}`
I get `user.list.link.many` in place of the string in teh template

Comment: If the translation isn't found, it's the key which is used. And it's not possible to choose a translation with such a key. Maybe the error is due to the spaces between your translation and in my example. Try `user.list.link|user.list.link.many`. (And of course, use the same in your catalog and clear your cache.)